# Processingでウインドウにリアルタイムで文字入力

Tags: processing

Processingのウインドウ上にキーボードで打った文字をリアルタイムで表示させていくにはどうすればいいですか？日本語で表示させていきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

PROCESSINGでは、標準の命令だけではIME経由で日本語入力を処理することはできません。PROCESSINGで日本語入力を受け付けたいのであれば、Swing/AWTを利用する事になります。「Swing Java」などのキーワードでググりましょう。もしも検索された技術情報を読んでもチンプンカンプンであれば、あなたにはまだ日本語入力を受け付けるプログラムを作るのは難しいかと思います。PROCESSINGを使って日本語入力をどうしても実現したいのであれば、JavaやGUIについて、必要な知識を勉強してみることをおすすめします。